# Convert column to Numpy within a select statement in Polars

Tags: python, numpy, datetime, select, python-polars

I am trying to transform a date column to the next business day after each date (if the date isn't already a business day in which case it remains unchanged). To do this I am using a Numpy function called busday_offset which takes a Numpy array as its first parameter. The line of code bellow doesn't work because pl.col('creation_date') isn't a Polars column but some kind of abstract object. Thus, ".to_numpy" can't be called on it to convert the column to a numpy array.

```
sales_orders.with_columns(
    [
        pl.lit(np.busday_offset(pl.col('creation_date').to_numpy(), 0, roll='forward'))
    ]
)
```

-> AttributeError: 'Expr' object has no attribute 'to_numpy'

I am aware that a workaround would be to use the ".get_column" method on the "sales_orders" table as such:

```
sales_orders.with_columns(
    [
        pl.lit(np.busday_offset(sales_orders.get_column('creation_date').to_numpy(), 0, roll='forward'))
    ]
)
```

But this lacks elegance and makes it impossible to have nested "with_columns" statements as such:

```
sales_orders.with_columns(
    [
        pl.lit(np.busday_offset(sales_orders.get_column('creation_date'), 0, roll='forward')).alias('order_acknowledgement_date')
    ]
).with_columns(
    [
        pl.lit(np.busday_offset(sales_orders.get_column('order_acknowledgement_date'), 2, roll='forward')).alias('ship_due_date')
    ]
)
```

-> ColumnNotFoundError: order_acknowledgement_date
This indeed doesn't work because "order_acknowledgement_date" isn't part of the "sales_orders" table.

**So my question is: how can I transform pl.col('creation_date') into a Numpy array within a select/with_columns statement without refering to the table sales_orders directly?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **Update:** Polars now understands [numpy.datetime64](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/pull/9783) objects as of `v0.18.7`

You can use [`.map()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.map.html)

```
df = pl.DataFrame({"date": ["2011-03-20", "2011-03-22", "2011-03-24"]})
df = df.with_columns(pl.col("date").str.to_date())

df.with_columns(busday = 
   pl.col("date").map(lambda date: 
      pl.Series(np.busday_offset(date, 0, roll="forward"))
   )
)
```

```
shape: (3, 2)
┌────────────┬────────────┐
│ date       ┆ busday     │
│ ---        ┆ ---        │
│ date       ┆ date       │
╞════════════╪════════════╡
│ 2011-03-20 ┆ 2011-03-21 │
│ 2011-03-22 ┆ 2011-03-22 │
│ 2011-03-24 ┆ 2011-03-24 │
└────────────┴────────────┘
```

Comment: Yes, the `.tolist()` is not ideal, and probably a big slowdown. If you check the last edit: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76636258/revisions you can try the astype/cast - I removed the edit until https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/pull/9783 is resolved.

Comment: Thank you for this answer! This code works but it is less efficient than the inelegant code that I am looking to replace. I implemented your solution on my dataset as follows:
1) (your solution) Takes 17 seconds (for a table with 2 million rows)
2) (the inelegant code) Takes 9 seconds
     this uses sales_orders.get_column('creation_date') in a first select/with_columns statement, then saves sales_orders and then uses sales_orders.get_column('order_acknowledgment_date') in a second seperate select/with_columns statement.
I still prefer your solution in my situation.

Comment: Great! Thank you so much! Replacing:
pl.col('creation_date').map(lambda date: 
      pl.Series(np.busday_offset(date, 0, roll='forward').tolist())
   )
by: 
pl.col('creation_date').map(lambda date: 
      pl.Series(np.busday_offset(date, 0, roll='forward').astype("datetime64[ms]")).cast(pl.Date)
   )
Reduced the time from 17 seconds to 0.4 seconds (for a 2 million row table).

Comment: I didn't realize it would be that much of a slowdown ^_^ - thanks for the update. I've rolled back the answer to remove the mention of `.tolist()`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the [polars-xdt](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars-xdt) plugin:

example:

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({"date": ["2011-03-20", "2011-03-22", "2011-03-24"]})
df = df.with_columns(pl.col("date").str.to_date())

df.with_columns(
    date_shifted=xdt.offset_by("date", "0bd", roll='forward'),
)
```

output:

```
Out[21]:
shape: (3, 2)
┌────────────┬──────────────┐
│ date       ┆ date_shifted │
│ ---        ┆ ---          │
│ date       ┆ date         │
╞════════════╪══════════════╡
│ 2011-03-20 ┆ 2011-03-21   │
│ 2011-03-22 ┆ 2011-03-22   │
│ 2011-03-24 ┆ 2011-03-24   │
└────────────┴──────────────┘
```